# Range aggregation in elasticsearch 5.2

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem with `range aggrigation` in elasticsearh v5.2. I want to filter documents that are in specific range and then aggrigate them in `histogram` bucket. but in the aggrigation results there is some bucket out of range values. is it a bug?

query :

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "some query",
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "body",
              "jobTag"
            ],
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "jobType": [
                  "PART_TIME",
                  "INTERNSHIP",
                  "FULL_TIME"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "lc": {
                  "gte": 98210000,
                  "lte": 98219999
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "location_bulks": {
      "range": {
        "field": "lc",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": 98210000,
            "to": 98219999
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "locations_range": {
          "histogram": {
            "field": "lc",
            "interval": 1000,
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "order": {
              "_count": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
{
  "took": 11,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": { ... },
  "aggregations": {
    "location_bulks": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "9.821E7-9.8219999E7",
          "from": 98210000,
          "to": 98219999,
          "doc_count": 12026,
          "locations_range": {
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": 98210000,
                "doc_count": 3639
              },
              {
                "key": 98212000,
                "doc_count": 2014
              },
              {
                "key": 98218000,
                "doc_count": 1997
              },
              {
                "key": 98313000,   // <==== out of range
                "doc_count": 11
              },
              {
                "key": 98263000,  // <==== out of range
                "doc_count": 10
              },
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i tested your aggregation query and is working fine on my machine. Can you also post your query in your post as query do effect the scope of the aggregations

Comment: @user3775217 I edited the questin